# How to process invokeAll EntryProcessor from map/set's values in custom order?

Tags: ignite

For the function:

```
 invokeAll()
```

It use Map/Set which contains the entry will be processed, I want process the each entry in a custom order, i.e as the same of the key order
in document:

> The order that the entries for the keys are processed is undefined. Implementations may choose to process the entries in any order, including concurrently. Furthermore there is no guarantee implementations will use the same EntryProcessor instance to process each entry, as the case may be in a non-local cache topology.

For this line:

> Implementations may choose to process the entries in any order, including concurrently

I don't know how to do this, is there any example?
If I use a TreeMap/TreeSet to save the key with order, does the entry will be handled same as its key order in the TreeMap/TreeSet?

By the way, as invoke has a internal lock, does invokeAll will also hold the lock for all the keys in map / set, until the entryprocessor finished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation you're referring to is, in fact, inherited from [`javax.cache.Cache::invokeAll`](https://static.javadoc.io/javax.cache/cache-api/1.0.0/javax/cache/Cache.html#invokeAll(java.util.Set,%20javax.cache.processor.EntryProcessor,%20java.lang.Object...)). "Implementation" here means not an `EntryProcessor` but an implementation of the JSR 166 (AKA JCache, AKA `javax.cache` package) - and Ignite implements it in `IgniteCache`.

What this documentation means is that specification of the `javax.cache.Cache` interface allows its implementations to invoke `EntryProcessor`s in any order. Ignite chooses not give any additional details to it, and there is not way to influence the order here.

Also, remember that Ignite is distributed, so the processing of entries in `invokeAll` is inherently concurrent. If you need strict order, it's probably better to iterate over the keys and use `invoke` on each key.

Comment: so, if i configured the cache with cache mode REPLICATED, add then using TreeSet to save all keys, then call invokeAll, does this could ensure the entry has been visited in order? I have write a sample using TreeMap,and check the tranverse output,  it seems the items has been visted in the TreeMap order, i use invokeAll instead invoke, as i fear of when invoke entry by entry update values, the value may changed/updated by other thread which also modify on this cache, but the invokeAll could add lock many entries at the same time to prevent other thead update to the entry values and more faster

Comment: @dvlcis EntryProcessors will be called concurrently, so it's not correct to talk about the order of execution. If you call this method on a transactional cache, then locks will be acquired in order, according to the provided map. But actual execution will happen in arbitrary order.